# What is the overhead of tracking in Entity Framework 3.1?

Tags: performance, entity-framework, entity-framework-core, ef-core-3.1, change-tracking

*Note: This is a follow up of [What is the overhead of Entity Framework tracking?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8257523/what-is-the-overhead-of-entity-framework-tracking) which asks about a rather old version of Entity Framework.*

One of the team I am working with have used [no tracking behavior at global level](http://dotnetblogpost.com/2017/11/19/entity-framework-core-performance-tips-disable-tracking-queries/) rather than at context or query level. This lead to strange code in the repositories since all injected context instances are not tracked: adding requires manual attaching, update has to explicit and some other explicit code related to navigation properties.

When asked about this, they invoked performance reasons, but failed to indicate a source.

My solution would be to use no tracking at context instance level. This would remove virtually all cumbersome code related to saving changes and the only issue would be when the programmer forgets to set no tracking for the instance. My assumption is that would not be such a big deal under normal circumstances (trees of several hundreds models).

[This article](http://www.krisvandermast.com/post/2018/02/03/Use-AsNoTracking-to-speed-up-Entity-Framework-performance.html) suggests a big difference (both memory and CPU) between systematic usage of no tracking and everything tracked, but it is not clear if this only related to this (the difference seems much bigger than just the cloned data required for tracking).

**Question:** What is the overhead of tracking in Entity Framework 3.1?

Comment: You make it seem that tracking on or off is set in stone. But you're in the driver's seat. You can instantiate the same context class with or without tracking. So, for example in disconnected scenario's, read without tracking, update with tracking. Attaching entities manually just because EF was told not to attach them is quite silly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is the overhead of tracking in Entity Framework 3.1?

It's exactly the same as attaching every entity you query to the change tracker manually.

You can also opt-in to tracking for a single query with [.AsTracking()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.entityframeworkqueryableextensions.astracking?view=efcore-3.1).

Comment: Thanks for the quick info. I am interested in more details if these are available. More specifically memory and CPU usage overhead (I expect the memory to be double or more, but CPU usage should not be that big). In this case `AsTracking` is a good suggestion as it allows a decent save functionality while keeping the global no tracking in place.

Comment: You should measure the performance in your scenario if you need it to make a decision.  The cost of change tracking is a function of the number of tracked entities, and so if you don't retrieve lots of entities, or have a DbContext instance with a long lifetime, it's usually negligible.